# Верстка странички flex

Tags: html, css

При написании шапки к сайту возникли несколько вопросов

1. Как убрать отступы вокруг шапки
2. Как выровнять текст по центру или
   убрать отступ что стоит перед текстом
3. Почему не создается отступ по
   левому краю элемента `ul`
4. Как выровнять элементы по центру, а то они
   сместились.(`margin-bottom` не помогает)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

index.php

```
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="top_menu">
        <div class="top_menu_items">
            <ul class="ul_top_items">
                <li class="ul_top_items_element_1">Element 1</li>
                <li class="ul_top_items_element_2">Element 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

style.css

```
.top_menu{
    height: 10%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.top_menu_items{
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}

.ul_top_items{
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: beige;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

ul{
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код не сложный, я надеюсь, что вы поймете код без комментариев

```css
body {margin: 0;}
.top_menu{
    height: 10%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.ul_top_items{
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color: beige;
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="top_menu">
        <div class="top_menu_items">
            <ul class="ul_top_items">
                <li class="ul_top_items_element_1">Element1&nbsp</li>
                <li class="ul_top_items_element_2">Element2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```